# ngx-bootstrap - Can't resolve all parameters for BsModalService in unit tests

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal

I am using ngx-bootstrap's (3.0.1) ModalService to show a modal dialog containing a component

```
this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(MyDialogComponent);
```

and I have this in my unit test (run by jest)

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [MyComponent, MyDialogComponent],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    providers: [MyService],
    imports: [
      ModalModule.forRoot(),
    ],
  })
  .compileComponents();
}));
```

The stubborn error tells me **Can't resolve all parameters for BsModalService: (?, ?).** The answers I was able to find were mentioning lack of a proper `@Injectable()` decorator, but this is obviously beyond my control and besides all it is irrelevant and misleading - the decorator is present in the source code of ngx-bootstrap.

I tried to explicitly provide all the components and services from the package (rather than ModuleWithProviders, but this didn't help either.

Running short of ideas.

#### Update 1

Tried commenting in and out

```
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

in plyfills.ts. Doesn't seem to matter. Unless there is a Jest config setting associated with that that I am missing?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: Regretfully not. I ended up ditching Bs dialog and wrote my own lightweight solution, based on ngrx store, no flaky services anymore.

Comment: That strange even when i provided a working solution on stackblitz. Ah ok, maybe that could be possibly be conflicting with that setup of your app.

Answer (score 0):

try to import core-js/es7/reflect in your polyfills.ts, it's needed to make your test work

```
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

Comment: You mean in `/src/polyfills.ts`? It had been enabled by cli, by default.

Answer (score 0):

As the service from BsModalService dynamically populates the DOM (entryComponents) you can take use of [BrowserDynamicTestingModule](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser-dynamic/testing/BrowserDynamicTestingModule) API by adding into the configureTestingModule:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ ModalModule.forRoot() ],
    declarations: [ MyDialogComponent ],
}).overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
  set: {
    entryComponents: [ HelloComponent ],
  }
}).compileComponents();
```

}));

trigger template elements(e.g. a button) with the [dispatch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) API and then just check if it pops up in the DOM.

here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-modal-test) with a live example.

**NOTE:** As the ngx [BsModalService](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#bs-modal-service) populates the DOM as a sibling to the root node of angular i was not able to use the Angular API to select the modal element so instead i had to use DOM [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). If someone has a better way please comment so i can update